# Can i use a Mage::getModel function on a View instead of a Table?

Tags: magento

I created a mysql view that joins around 7 tables and i want to use the  Mage::getModel function on that view. Is it possible ? Also can i use the joinTable function on a mysql View instead of a mySql Table ? any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably create an entity around such a view, but you won't be able to write to the underlying data structures. Also, if this is an extension you intend to distribute, you may run into problems with permissions for creating views.

MySQL views are treated -- for the most part -- like tables, so yes you can join against a view.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks ! I was able to join the view